# Generalization of an absorbing Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains, expected-value

> A process moves on the integers 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. It starts at 1 and, on each
>   successive step, moves to an integer greater than its present position, moving
>   with equal probability to each of the remaining larger integers. State five is
>   an absorbing state. Find the expected number of steps to reach state five.

I solved using matrices.

If there are $r$ absorbing states and $t$ transient states,
the transition matrix will have the following canonical form

$P$ = $\begin{bmatrix}Q&R\\O&I\end{bmatrix}$

Here all the submatrices are transition matrices. $I$ is an $r$-by-$r$ identity matrix, $O$ is an $r$-by-$t$ zero matrix, $R$ is a nonzero $t$-by-$r$ matrix, and $Q$ is an $t$-by-$t$ matrix.

If $N = I + Q + Q^2 + ... = (I-Q)^{-1}$

If we add all the entries in the $i^{th}$ row of $N$, we will have the expected
number of times in any of the transient states for a given starting state $s_{i}$, that is, the expected time required before being absorbed.

Now let $t_{i}$ be the expected number of steps before the chain is absorbed,
given that the chain starts in state $s_{i}$, and let $t$ be the column vector whose $i^{th}$ entry is $t_{i}$. Then

$t = Nc$ ,

where $c$ is a column vector all of whose entries are $1$.

So the answer here is the first element of $t$ or the sum of all elements of first row in $N$.

But how to generalize and get the answer for $n$ numbers? Please help. I think there should be another easier approach other than matrices.

Question and Solution Reference: **Grinstead, C.M. and Snell, J.L., 2012. Introduction to probability. American Mathematical Soc.**

Edit:
I am trying to solve this using recursion.
$E(i)$ denotes the expected no. of steps to reach $n$ starting from number $i$.
So,

$E(i) = 1+\frac{1}{n-i}\sum_{k=i+1}^{n-1}E(k)$

and base cases: $E(n) = 0$ and $E(n-1) = 1$.

Using these base values, I manually solved recursion for smaller numbers by substitution and found:

$E(i) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-i}\frac{1}{k}$

But now how to prove this relation for all numbers?

Comment: All this can be bypassed using the classical one-step Markov chain decomposition, to the effect that, if $t_n$ denotes the mean number of steps when there are $n$ remining spots, then $t_1=1$ and $$t_{n+1}=1+\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nt_k$$ which is readily solved by $$t_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$ and your answer is $t_4$.

Comment: Nice. How did you come up with this formula?

Comment: Quote: "using the classical one-step Markov chain decomposition".

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand chain decomposition. I could come up with a very similar  recursion equation but cannot come to your second solution equation.

Comment: Then show what you can do and explain why the steps which escape you, are a problem.

Comment: Ok. I added in the question what I have tried.

Comment: Did you note how I defined $t_n$ in my post? Please be more careful...

Comment: Yes I do see how $t_{n}$ is defined and is different from E(i) and by substitution I can come to the answer. But I am unable to prove this relation in general. I don't know how to solve recursion without substitution and induction.